# alert function in javaScript

Tags: javascript, scope

Can someone help me to better understand why the second alert box appears with 'undefined' in it? When I call the function without alert function I don't see it.

```
var n = 1;  // global scope

function one() {
alert(n);
} 
alert(one());
```

Comment: the second alert is trying to alert the return value of the one() function -- but it doesn't return anything.

Comment: or to put it another way - what would you expect the second alert to display?

Comment: There are no local variables in your code. What does that part of the question title refer to?

Comment: @Barmar scope is confusing me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`alert(one())` alerts the return value of the function `one`. That function *does not return a value*, so its return value is `undefined`.

If you want to change the value of the second `alert`, you need to use `return <value>` from within `one`.

```js
var n = 1;  // global scope

function one() {
  alert(n);
  return 42;
} 
alert(one());
```